# How to change the font color in the textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, colors

If I want to upload a text file into the textbox and want to highlight
certain words with a font color change, how can I do that without 
drawing the text?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that a textbox or richtextbox?

Comment: Using what technology? WinForms?  WPF?

Comment: This question can't be answered without at least telling us whether you're asking about a desktop or a web application. (I suspect it's the latter.)

Comment: I am running this on Visual Studio, C# Windows Application. 
And I am working with the regular textbox from the tool menu.

Comment: You cannot do it with a regular textbox control.  RTB required.

Comment: RTB immediately adds double line spacing, which isn't fixable without WPF as far as I know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the font color of some substring in the textbox in C# Winform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119947/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-some-substring-in-the-textbox-in-c-sharp-winform)

Answer (score 40):

Assuming WinForms, the [ForeColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez1ywchy(v=VS.71).aspx) property allows to change **all the text** in the `TextBox` (not just what you're about to add):

```
TextBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

To only change the color of certain words, look at [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).

Comment: this does not "highlight certain words" but changes the colour of all words. I don't think this is a correct answer

Comment: The OP has clearly specified that he wants to highlight through a `font colour change`... So all he needs to do is change the colour.

Comment: But he specified "highlight certain words" and if you change the ForeColor of the Text, all the text will change, not the "certain words".

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I believe the RichTextBox can do it, though I have never used it myself. You're maybe right about the "certain words", though.

Comment: it depends on if by highlighting he meant changing text colour or highlighting like with a highlighter

Comment: Though keep in mind that if the textbox control is disabled (Enabled == false), the ForeColor property is ignored.

Comment: If you have a readonly textbox, you must set the backcolor (e.g. `TextBox.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;`) before setting the ForeColor

Answer (score 4):

RichTextBox will allow you to use html to specify the color. Another alternative is using a listbox and using the DrawItem event to draw how you would like. AFAIK, textbox itself can't be used in the way you're hoping.