# How to print color text

Tags: c#, colors

```
if (counter == 0)
     textBox2.Text += "ERROR: the item in the  " + j + "th row is wrong" + Environment.NewLine;
```

How do I print j variable Red when it appears in TextBox?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813522/how-to-change-the-font-color-in-the-textbox-in-c

Comment: Simple answer: use RichTextBox http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx

Comment: If this is the ASP.NET you can use Validators for this purposes which are displaying text in red color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just change the color for the whole font. Use `textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red`

Or use `RichTextBox`

Answer (score 2):

First, make it a rich text box instead of a regular textbox.

Then

```
Font fnt=new Font("Verdana", 8F, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point);
string mystring=@" " + j + "th";
if (richTextBox1.Find(mystring)>0)
{
    int my1stPosition=richTextBox1.Find(mystring);
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart=my1stPosition;
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength=mystring.Length; 
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont=fnt;
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor=Color.CadetBlue;
}
```

Comment: mmm well maybe you did fix the search string (`mystring`). Or maybe not

Comment: I made it `string mystring=@""+j + 1+"th";`  Correct ?

Comment: @georgemano: I can't tell from the code you gave. Just select _exactly_ the bit of text that you want coloured. You know best what bit of text it is. Including the whitespace to the left/right prevents accidental replacements if the number appears as a part of some other word somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with an standard `TextBox`, you need to use a [RichTextbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx)

Then, take a look about how to [highlight words in a RichTextBox](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=146).

Hope it helps.