# Printing colored words in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am writing in a RichTextBox .

How do I make the lineItems and the j+1 variable be printed in **red**.

For example(in bold = red): *Element **Growthougth** in **4** th column, has not been writen right.*

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
//  Numbers-IDs
        if (colB[j] == "int_number")
        {
           if (!arithmos(lineItems[j]))
               richTextBox1.Text += "Element    " + lineItems[j] + "\t in   " + (j + 1) + "th coloumn,has not been writen right" + Environment.NewLine;
        }

// Alphanumeric  
        else if (colB[j] == "alpharithmitiko")
        {
              if (!numword(lineItems[j]))
                  richTextBox1.Text += "Element    " + lineItems[j] + "   in  " + (j + 1) + "th coloumn,has not been writen right " + Environment.NewLine;
        }



//Words
        else if (colB[j] == "words")
        {
                if (!word(lineItems[j]))
                    richTextBox1.Text += "Το στοιχείο    " + lineItems[j] + "    in  " + (j + 1) + "th coloumn,has not been writen right" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
//Date
        else if (colB[j] == "date")
        {
             if (!date(lineItems[j]))
                 richTextBox1.Text += "Το στοιχείο    " + lineItems[j] + "    in  " + (j+1) + "th coloumn,has not been writen right" + Environment.NewLine;
          }
}
```

Comment: @Reniuz Take a look at my edit

Comment: is changing text forecolor not working?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string

Comment: The answer by user "sehe" [for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791310/how-to-print-color-text/7791355#7791355) is the same solution for you.

Comment: Which are you using: WPF or Winforms?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
if (!arithmos(lineItems[j]))
richTextBox1.Text += "Element    " + lineItems[j] + "\t in   " + (j + 1) + "th coloumn,has not been writen right" + Environment.NewLine;
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox1.AppendText(j + 1);
```

Comment: where do i write this ? Under the if-statement? Inside the method or outside ?

Comment: What do you mean _got_? I have a `for-statement` with `j` the variable , and I print it sometimes alone, and sometimes `lineItems[j]`. Where?