# How to change the font color of some substring in the textbox in C# Winform?

Tags: c#, colors, textbox, substring

If I want to upload a text file into the textbox and want to highlight certain words with a font color change, i know that i need to write `TextBox.ForeColor = Color.SomeColor;`
But if i want that **not all the text will be in the *same* color**, only some Substrings.
How can I do that?

Comment: [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the answer  by [Pieter Joost van de Sande](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/84b16f2d-9596-4095-bb0e-92354114a694/).

> You can't do this in the TextBox control, only in the RichTextBox control.

```
if( myRichTextBox.TextLenght >= 5 )
{
myRichTextBox.Select( 0, 5 );
myRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
}

if( myRichTextBox.TextLenght >= 15 )
{
myRichTextBox.Select( 10, 15 );
myRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @syed-mohsin answered, it's possible to add text, then select portions of the text and change its color.

It's also possible to not select anything, set `SelectionColor`, and any appended text (eg through `AppendText` or `Text +=`) will have that color, until you change `SelectionColor` again. For example:

`richTextBox.AppendText("default color");
richTextBox.SelectionColor(Color.Green);
richTextBox.AppendText("that will be in green");
richTextBox.SelectionColor(Color.Red);
richTextBox.AppendText("that will be in red");
richTextBox.SelectionColor(Color.Black);
richTextBox.AppendText("that will be in black");`